# aiohttp 1->2 with gunicorn unable to use timeout context manager

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My small `aiohttp1` app was working fine until I have started preparing for deploying to Heroku servers. Heroku forces me to use `gunicorn`. It wasn't working with `aiohttp1` (some strange errors), and after a small migration `aiohttp2` I have started app with

```
gunicorn app:application --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornUVLoopWebWorker
```

command and I works, until I have requested view that calls class' async method with

```
with async_timeout.timeout(self.timeout):
    res = await self.method()
```

code inside and it raises `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` error.

The only thing that changed until last successful version: the fact that I'm using `gunicorn`. I'm using `Python 3.5.2` and `uvloop 0.8.0` and `gunicorn 19.7.1`.

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

**UPD**

The problem is that I have `LOOP` variable that store **newly created** event loop. This variable definition is in `setting.py` file, so before `aiohttp.web.Application` creating, code below gets evaluated:

```
LOOP = uvloop.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_evet_loop(LOOP)
```

and this causes error when using `async_timeout.timeout` context manager.

Code to reproduce the error:

```
# test.py
from aiohttp import web
import uvloop
import asyncio
import async_timeout
asyncio.set_event_loop(uvloop.new_event_loop())
class A:
    async def am(self):
        with async_timeout.timeout(timeout=1):
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
class B:
    a = A()
    async def bm(self):
        await self.a.am()
b = B()
async def hello(request):
    await b.bm()
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")
app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', hello)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, port=5000, host='localhost')
```

and just run `gunicorn test:app --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornUVLoopWebWorker` (same error when using `GunicornWebWorker` with `uvloop` event loop, or any other combination).

**solution**

I have fixed this by calling `asyncio.get_event_loop` when I need to use event loop.

Comment: Heroku doesn't force you to use gunicorn.

Comment: @dim I can just deploy `aiohttp` app and set it to listen on a specific port and host? Can you tell more?

Comment: You probably want the host to be 0.0.0.0 and the port needs to be the `PORT` environment variable that Heroku sets, but yeah. Here's an [example of using uWSGI](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/tutorials/heroku_python.rst).

Comment: The error is very strange. Could you provide a code for reproducing the problem?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov today I have continued configuring for deploy and app just works well. After a while, I understood that the problem was with my loop settings: I'm creating new `uvloop` in my `settings.py` before app creation. But the exception isn't helpful anyway. I'm trying to reproduce error with small piece of code.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov should I create an Issue on `async_timeout` GitHub repository because I think that the error message doesn't provide any helpful information about what is wrong?

Comment: Please do. Honestly I have no idea for better message but we could discuss it on github.